# install pgAdmin4 with yum

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is there already a way to install the pgAdmin IV Beta desktop runtime e.g. with yum? I found the download link for the Python wheel on the official site, but no hint for yum. It seems the desktop runtime is not available yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pgAdmin 4 is included in the official [PostgreSQL yum repository](https://yum.postgresql.org/).

Add the [RPM corresponding to your distribution](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) and run:

```
sudo yum install pgadmin4
```

Comment: this returns 
`Loaded plugins: langpacks

No package pgadmin4 available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: @Michael Do you have the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository installed?

Comment: Yes, and PostgreSQL RPM for yum as well.

Comment: @Michael the repository is broken; the owner is working on it https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CABcP5fjGADmGE%2BC6krYo-bAQUv73gyo4JxsqXpWDuGJX%2BOvX%3DQ%40mail.gmail.com#CABcP5fjGADmGE+C6krYo-bAQUv73gyo4JxsqXpWDuGJX+OvX=Q@mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the EPEL and pdgd-9x-centos repos enabled

> yum install pgadmin4-v1

Answer (score -1):

If you have a problem when you try install pgadmin4

```
$ yum -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

$ yum -y install pgadmin4
```

ERROR:

> Transaction check error:   file /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5 from install of
> libpq5-13.0-10PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
> postgresql-libs-9.2.24-4.el7_8.x86_64

use:

```
$ sudo yum -y install pgadmin4 -x libpq5*
```

...
then libpq5... will be ignored and it will be installed